# Two Querys in one Search - Category-Tag nightmare - HOW?

Tags: search

Dream scenario:

User searches for at state (post tag) to find a relevant service. Every state has its own tag and category. If no service (post) is found a text pops up  - something in the region of "No service in this specific state - but hey! maybe you could use the service in one of the neighbouring states? And voila! The neighbouring states (post category) appeares.

Current scenario:

Reality has hit: search.php is not my friend. Child theme is CONFUSED by all the testing...
As a result I´ve turned to the Plugin marked. Searched high and low: no search plugins have this as an option.
Is it even possible using if, else and echo? How, in Gods name - HOW?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your post types/taxonomies, and/or show your current code? Reading the "Dream Scenario," it sounds like each "Service post" is tagged with it's State, as well as each neighboring state in a separate taxonomy? Or is "neighboring states" some hard-coded list, and you only store the service's state? What you're asking is totally possible - it's just not clear what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

"What you're asking is totally possible" has me way to exited!
I wish I had some code examlpe - but in a rage yesterday I deleted everything thinking it would be best with a fresh start.

"it sounds like each "Service post" is tagged with it's State, as well as each neighboring state in a separate taxonomy?" - Correct. Search is for a tag(name) and if no tag name then for category(names).

I am using twenty-twenty - if that helps...